# Отправка SQL запроса с файла на PHP7

Tags: php, sql

Есть база данных `wp_database` на ней есть таблица `wp_rcl_chat_messages` из которой по SQL запросу удаляется все , что создано больше дня назад:

```
DELETE FROM wp_database.wp_rcl_chat_messages 
WHERE (message_time < DATE_SUB(NOW(),INTERVAL 1 DAY))
```

Я хочу , чтобы эта проверка происходила автоматически , для этого сделал файл на PHP и закинул его в `cron`. Так вот , файл не запускается совсем , даже если отправлять `php /home/1.php`. Не знаете , в чем может быть проблема ?

Код PHP:

```
<?php 
$connect = mysqli_connect("192.168.0.101", "root","password", "wp.database"); 
{ 
$sql = "DELETE FROM wp.database.wp_rcl_chat_messages WHERE (message_time < DATE$ 
} 
?>
```

Comment: `Так вот , файл не запускается совсем` почему он должен запускаться, если код даже близко не соответствует правилам написания кода php? Идете и читаете мануалы тут http://php.net/manual/ru/index.php

Comment: Сделал как в образце http://php.net/manual/ru/mysqli.error.php `<?php
$mysqli = new mysqli("192.168.0.101", "root", "password", "wp_database");

/* check connection */
if ($mysqli->connect_errno) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", $mysqli->connect_error);
    exit();



}

$sql = "DELETE FROM wp_rcl_chat_messages WHERE (message_time < DATE_SUB(NOW(),INTERVAL 1 DAY))";

/* close connection */
$mysqli->close();

?>` все равно не работает